# Why is predict.glmnet not predicting probabilities?

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm working on a model to predict the probability that college baseball players will make the major leagues. My dataset has 633 observations and 13 predictors with a binary response. The code below generates smaller reproducible examples of training and testing datasets:

```
set.seed(1)
OBP <- rnorm(50, mean=1, sd=.2)
HR.PCT <- rnorm(50, mean=1, sd=.2)
AGE <- rnorm(50, mean=21, sd=1)
CONF <- sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), size=50, replace=TRUE)
CONF <- factor(CONF, levels=c("A","B","C","D","E"))
df.train <- data.frame(OBP, HR.PCT, AGE, CONF)
df.train <- df.train[order(-OBP),]
df.train$MADE.MAJORS <- 0
df.train$MADE.MAJORS[1:10] <- 1

OBP <- rnorm(10, mean=1, sd=.2)
HR.PCT <- rnorm(10, mean=1, sd=.2)
AGE <- rnorm(10, mean=21, sd=1)
CONF <- sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), size=10, replace=TRUE)
CONF <- factor(CONF, levels=c("A","B","C","D","E"))
MADE.MAJORS <- sample(0:1, size=10, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.8,0.2))
df.test <- data.frame(OBP, HR.PCT, AGE, CONF, MADE.MAJORS)
```

I then used `glmnet` to perform the lasso with logistic regression and generate predictions. I want the predictions to be in the form of probabilities (that is, between 0 and 1).

```
library(glmnet)
train.mtx <- with(df.train, model.matrix(MADE.MAJORS ~ OBP + HR.PCT + AGE + CONF)[,-1])
glmmod <- glmnet(x=train.mtx, y=as.factor(df.train$MADE.MAJORS), alpha=1, family="binomial")
cv.glmmod <- cv.glmnet(x=train.mtx, y=df.train$MADE.MAJORS, alpha=1)

test.mtx <- with(df.test, model.matrix(MADE.MAJORS ~ OBP + HR.PCT + AGE + CONF)[,-1])
preds <- predict.glmnet(object=glmmod, newx=test.mtx, s=cv.glmmod$lambda.min, type="response")
cv.preds <- predict.cv.glmnet(object=cv.glmmod, newx=test.mtx, s="lambda.min")
```

Here are the predictions:

```
> preds
            1
1  -3.2589440
2  -0.4435265
3   3.9646670
4   0.3772816
5   0.9952887
6  -7.3555661
7   0.2283675
8  -2.3871317
9  -8.1632749
10 -1.3563051

> cv.preds
            1
1   0.1568839
2   0.3630938
3   0.7435941
4   0.4808428
5   0.5261076
6  -0.1431655
7   0.4123054
8   0.2207381
9  -0.1446941
10  0.2962391
```

I have a few questions about these results. Feel free to answer any or all (or none) of them. I'm most interested in an answer for the first question.

1. Why are the predictions from `predict.glmnet` (the `preds` vector) not in the form of probabilities? I put the `preds` values through the inverse logit function and got reasonable probabilities. Was that correct?
2. The predictions from `predict.cv.glmnet` (the `cv.preds` vector) mostly look like probabilities, but some of them are negative. Why is this?
3. When I use the `glmnet` function to create the glmmod object, I include the `family="binomial"` argument to indicate that I'm using logistic regression. However, when I use the `cv.glmnet` function to find the best value for lambda, I'm not able to specify logistic regression. Am I actually getting the best value for lambda if the cross-validation doesn't use logistic regression?
4. Similarly, when I use the `predict.cv.glmnet` function, I'm not able to specify logistic regression. Does this function produce the predictions that I want?

Comment: This belongs on CrossValidated.

Comment: Thank you. How can I move it to CrossValidated?

Comment: You can flag it or you can wait for two more people to agree with me. That's what the close votes will be doing.

Comment: @42-, these all seem like coding questions to me, rather than interpretation questions. SO seems like the right place for it.

Comment: Seemed to me that they were all about failing to understand the underlying principles of generalized regression functions.

Comment: @42, I think the OP has it right, I think it's a coding question.

Comment: Regardless, the questions are about how to get `predict` to provide probabilities, and how to ensure that `cv.glmnet` uses a `logit` link function, which are quintessentially coding questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure on the following because the package does seem to operate counter to its documentation, as you've noticed, but it may produce some indication whether your thinking is along the right path.

#### Question 1

Yes, you're right. Note that,

```
> predict.glmnet(object=glmmod, newx=test.mtx, s=cv.glmmod$lambda.min, type="link")
            1
1  -3.2589440
2  -0.4435265
3   3.9646670
4   0.3772816
5   0.9952887
6  -7.3555661
7   0.2283675
8  -2.3871317
9  -8.1632749
10 -1.3563051
```

which is the same output as `type="response"`. Thus, putting it through the inverse logit function would be the right way to get the probabilities. As to why is this happening, I have not clue -perhaps a bug.

#### Question 2...4

For the `cv.preds`, you're getting something along the lines of probabilities because you're fitting a Gaussian link. In order to fit a logit link, you should specify the `family` parameter. Namely:

```
cv.glmmod <- cv.glmnet(x=train.mtx, y=df.train$MADE.MAJORS, alpha=1, family="binomial")

> cv.preds
            1
1  -10.873290
2    1.299113
3   15.812671
4    3.622259
5    5.621857
6  -24.826551
7    1.734000
8   -5.420878
9  -26.160403
10  -4.496020
```

In this case, `cv.preds` will output along the real line and you can put those values through the inverse logit to get the probabilities.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I hadn't realized that the `cv.glmnet` function could take a `family` argument.

Comment: Can i ask - why are `cv.preds` and `preds` needed here? I mean, i would have expected only one vector of predictions, but here we seem to be using two

Comment: @baxx sorry for the late response. Not sure why both are needed. The two vectors represent the same values but in different form. Consider the model  $p_i=\frac{\exp(\betaX_i)}{\exp(\beta X_i)+1}$ . In the OP's question, `preds` refer to \betaX_i while the `cv.preds` refer to $p_i$. In the question, I only refer to $\betaX_i$ (ie `cv.preds`) but if you were to put the `cv.preds` through the inverse-logit, you'll get the predicted probabilities.